# Why error, "alias target name does not lie within the target zone" in Terraform aws_route53_record?

Tags: amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

With Terraform 0.12, I am creating a static web site in an S3 bucket:

```
...

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "www" {
  bucket = "example.com"
  acl    = "public-read"
  policy = <<-POLICY
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"]
      }]
    }
    POLICY
  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
    error_document = "404.html"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
    Terraform = "true"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = "example.com"

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
    Terraform = "true"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "main-ns" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = "example.com"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = aws_s3_bucket.www.website_endpoint
    zone_id                = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error: [ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch:
[Tried to create an alias that targets example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com., type A in zone Z1P...9HY, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone, 
 Tried to create an alias that targets example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com., type A in zone Z1P...9HY, but that target was not found]
    status code: 400, request id: 35...bc

  on main.tf line 132, in resource "aws_route53_record" "main-ns":
 132: resource "aws_route53_record" "main-ns" {
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `zone_id` within `alias` is the S3 bucket zone ID, not the Route 53 zone ID. The correct `aws_route53_record` resource is:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "main-ns" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = "example.com"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = aws_s3_bucket.www.website_endpoint
    zone_id                = aws_s3_bucket.www.hosted_zone_id    # Corrected
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Here is an example for CloudFront. The variables are:

```
base_url = example.com
cloudfront_distribution = "EXXREDACTEDXXX"
domain_names = ["example.com", "www.example.com"]
```

The Terraform code is:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "this" {
  name = var.base_url
}

data "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "this" {
  id = var.cloudfront_distribution
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "this" {
  for_each = toset(var.domain_names)
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.this.zone_id
  name = each.value
  type = "A"
  alias {
    name    = data.aws_cloudfront_distribution.this.domain_name
    zone_id = data.aws_cloudfront_distribution.this.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Many users specify CloudFront `zone_id = "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2"` because it's always `Z2FDTNDATAQYW2`...until some day maybe it isn't. I like to avoid the literal string by computing it using data source `aws_cloudfront_distribution`.

Comment: Putting this here for anyone looking for it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_AliasTarget.html

For Cloudfront it's a standard `HostedZoneID: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2`

Comment: You commented just as I came here to add a CloudFront example!

Comment: Terraform has a nice example in their docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket#route53-record

Comment: Thanks Karl, exactly what I was after (S3 bucket Route53 Record example)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone like me that came here from Google in hope to find the syntax for the CloudFormation and YML, Here is how you can achieve it for your sub-domains.

Here we add a DNS record into the Route53 and redirect all the subnets of example.com to this ALB:

```
AlbDnsRecord:
    Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSet"
    DependsOn: [ALB_LOGICAL_ID]
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: "example.com."
      Type: "A"
      Name: "*.example.com."
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !GetAtt [ALB_LOGICAL_ID].DNSName
        EvaluateTargetHealth: False
        HostedZoneId: !GetAtt [ALB_LOGICAL_ID].CanonicalHostedZoneID
      Comment: "A record for Stages ALB"
```

My mistakes was:

- not adding `.` at the end of my `HostedZoneName`
- under `AliasTarget.HostedZoneId` ID is al uppercase in the end of `CanonicalHostedZoneID`
- replace the `[ALB_LOGICAL_ID]` with the actual name of your ALB, for me it was like: `ALBStages.DNSName`
- You should have the zone in your Route53.

So for us all the below addresses will come to this ALB:

- dev01.example.com
- dev01api.example.com
- dev02.example.com
- dev02api.example.com
- qa01.example.com
- qa01api.example.com
- qa02.example.com
- qa02api.example.com
- uat.example.com
- uatapi.example.com

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is trying to create a PHZ and 'A' recordset for a VPC endpoint, using cloudformation then below code will be useful.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  EC2Endpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.ec2'
      SubnetIds: 
        - subnet-1
        - subnet-2
        - subnet-3
      VpcEndpointType: Interface
      VpcId: vpc-id
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: EC2-Endpoint
  EC2PHZ:
    Type: "AWS::Route53::HostedZone"
    Properties: 
      HostedZoneConfig: 
        Comment: 'PHZ for ec2 vpc endpoint'
      Name: !Sub 'ec2.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'
      VPCs: 
        - 
          VPCId: vpc-id
          VPCRegion: !Ref "AWS::Region"
  EC2ARecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'ec2.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'
      HostedZoneId: !Ref EC2PHZ
      Type: A
      AliasTarget:
       HostedZoneId: !Select [0, !Split [":", !Select [0, !GetAtt EC2Endpoint.DnsEntries]]]
       DNSName: !Select [1, !Split [":", !Select [0, !GetAtt EC2Endpoint.DnsEntries]]]
```